# Partial derivative of the likelihood function respect to $\sigma^2$

Tags: derivatives

I am having problem doing the partial derivative of the likelihood function which is

$L(\mu,\sigma^2)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}^n}\times \exp{(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum(x_i-\mu)^2)}$

If the first part has solved that the $\hat{\mu}$ is $\bar{x}$
and plug this to the $L(x,\mu,\sigma)$
I wonder may I ask how to make the partial derivative to the $\sigma^2$
and the answer is 
$-n/2\sigma^2+1/2\sigma^4\times\sum(x_i-\mu)^2$

Thank you! I guess I did something wrong so I tried two times but did not get the above answer.

Appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We generally work with the **log** likelihood. Like the **log** function is increasing, the maximum of the likelihood is also the maximum of the log likelihood.

$$
\log{L(\mu,\sigma^2)}=-\frac{n}{2}\log{\sigma^2}-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^2+C
$$

where $C$ is a constant term (that does not depend on $\sigma$ or $\mu$). This constant is generally dropped because it does not play any role in our maximization.

Also note that in order to express everything in $\sigma^2$ (and not in $\sigma$) I have used this "trick": 
$$
\log{\sigma}=\log{(\sigma^2)^{1/2}}=\frac{1}{2}\log{\sigma^2}
$$ (valid because we assume $\sigma>0$)

Now you can compute your partial derivatives:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}(\log{L(\mu,\sigma^2)})=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum _{i=1}^n \left(x_i-\mu \right)
$$

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma^2}(\log{L(\mu,\sigma^2)})=\frac{\sum _{i=1}^n \left(x_i-\mu \right)^2}{2 \sigma ^4}-\frac{n}{2 \sigma
   ^2}
$$

Next to get $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ you must solve $\nabla\log{L(\mu,\sigma^2)}=\mathbf{0}$, that is:

$$
\sum _{i=1}^n \left(x_i-\mu \right) = 0
$$

$$
\sum _{i=1}^n \left(x_i-\mu \right)^2=n\sigma^2
$$

($\mu=\bar{x}$ and $\sigma^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum _{i=1}^n \left(x_i-\bar{x}\right)^2$)

---

**update (see comment):** clarification concerning 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma^2}(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2})=\frac{1}{2\sigma^4}
$$
which can be a little confusing.

You must realize that **"$\sigma^2$" must be interpreted purely as a symbol**. The previous calculation must be thought as follows:

In order to compute 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma^2}(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2})
$$
what you actually do is to replace the "symbol" $\sigma^2$ by $x$: 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(-\frac{1}{2x}) = \frac{1}{2x^2}
$$
then you reintroduce $\sigma^2$, the complete story is:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma^2}(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}) \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(-\frac{1}{2x}) = \frac{1}{2x^2} \equiv \frac{1}{2(\sigma^2)^2}= \frac{1}{2\sigma^4}
$$

---

*Another example (assuming that $\sigma>0$) would be:*
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma^2}\frac{1}{\sigma}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma^2}}\equiv\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=-\frac{1}{2 x^{3/2}}\equiv -\frac{1}{2 (\sigma^2)^{3/2}}=-\frac{1}{2\sigma^3}
$$

Comment: Very clear, thank you so much!!

Comment: @Chen happy if it helps :)

Comment: @Vincent, may I ask how did you come up with the $\sigma^4$? Mine has been $\sigma^3$ in the denominator. Thanks!!

Comment: @chen see my update, does it answer your question?

Comment: Thank you so much @Vincent, this is really helpful for me!!!

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why $\sigma^2$ must be interpreted as a symbol (and therefore the chain rule doesn't apply)? Relatedly, I've seen $\sigma$ used instead of $\sigma^2$ to find the mle of $\sigma^2$ (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dn6b9fCIUpM) -- is that wrong given that $\sigma^2$ must be treated as a symbol? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jtr13  The idea was to simplify the calculations a bit (reread my post update), but if it confuses you, you can forget all about it: this trick is absolutely not necessary. If you proceed as usual by deriving w.r.t. $\sigma$ you will get exactly the same result.

Comment: I understand now... thank you!